# Change the amount of variations displayed in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, constants, product-variations

By default Woocommerce loads 50 variations per run.

Searching the web, I found a line of code to be entered in the `functions.php` file, of my active child theme.

```
define( ‘WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS’, 150);
```

After copying it in the `functions.php` file, I did not get changes and the 50 variations are still being loaded and not 150 as I indicated in the line of code.

This is the functions.php file:

```
<?php

//CARGA EL STYLE.CSS DEL TEMA PADRE EN EL TEMA HIJO

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

//Incremento de las variaciones en Woocommerce  
define( ‘WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS’, 150);

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tested it on my local machine and found that `define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );` can be used either in the `functions.php` or `wp-config.php`.

It is not working for you because **`WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS`** is not properly enclosed by the single quote **`''`**, instead it is enclosed by apostrophe 
**`‘’`**:

- Incorrect: `define( ‘WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS’, 150 );`
- Correct: `define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );`

After making above correction, you can use this constant in any of the following ways:

1. Either put the correct code in your `functions.php` file;
2. Or completely remove it from your `functions.php` file and add it in your `wp-config.php` file

It should work for you.

**WARNING**

1. If you are going to increase the limit, be sure your server/hosting can handle the increased limit as it is resource intensive task.
2. If your data is not saving, it might be a server/hosting configuration issue as stated in the following WooCommerce documentation.

[Problems with large amounts of data not saving (variations, rates etc)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/)
.

Comment: Thank you Kashif Rafique, I made the correction as you suggested and with that change could load the 150 variations without problem. My hosting supported the execution.

Answer (score 2):

First you should use `'` *(single quotes)* in `‘WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS’` instead. Then, as this is related to Ajax, the best way is to define that constant using the `init` hook this way:

```
add_action( 'init', 'change_max_variations_linked' );
function change_max_variations_linked(){
    define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

*Or you can also add* `define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );` *to your* `wp-config.php` *file*.

> **Why:** This constant is defined in `WC_Ajax` Class in [`link_all_variations()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#645) method as follow:
>
> ```
> wc_maybe_define_constant( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 49 );
> ```
>
> So this way you define the constant before Woocommerce, where `wc_maybe_define_constant()` will not set any value for it, **making your setting active**.

---

See: [How can we improve WooCommerce? Increase max # of Variations](http://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/2915157-increase-max-of-variations)